# Sublime Text Shortcut for Opening the Last Closed Tab

Tags: sublimetext2

I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on chrome to reopen the last tabs I have closed by accident. Does the same type of thing exist in sublime or does it not cache that?

Comment: Useful info, but I can't understand why you would ask this question here rather than just trying it in Sublime yourself? Looking for kudos?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can find the shortcut to Windows (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd>) and Mac (<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd>).

I've just tested it on Windows and Mac and it works.

It only works for saved files.

Comment: Weird. I had tried that before and it didn't work but now it does. Maybe this will be useful for someone else. Sounds like a user error

Comment: That's weird. If you ever need more useful shortcuts to Sublime, then I just found http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/keyboard_shortcuts_win.html

I just found some new ones to use.

Answer (score 0):

For opening last closed window on Ubuntu, choose Project tab > Open Recent -> Choose window. Works for unregistered user as well.
I had lots of unsaved crucial data and Sublime saved it fortunately even on accidentally closing window.